# How to switch from one view to another?

Tags: iphone, ipad, ios

I have a window based application. What is the simplest way to switch from one view to another in this type of application?

Comment: Define "switch from one view to another." Do you want to push a new viewcontroller, or just throw away your current view and show a new one?

Comment: What does it mean "to push a new viewcontroller"? I'm newbie in iOS development.

Comment: If you have a UINavigationController in your application (probably not if you're making a window-based app), you can create a stack of viewcontrollers (objects that manage their views and provide logic for them) such that new ones can slide in or out.

Comment: Ok, I understand. But I don't have UINavigationController :)

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't using a navigation controller, and don't need to switch to a different view controller, then something like this will just switch views:

```
[ myCurrentTopView removeFromSuperView ];

[ window addSubView: myNewView ];
```

For this, you will need a reference to the current top view (myCurrentTopView in the above example), and might want to make sure your myNewView object is allocated, initialized, the proper frame size, etc. beforehand.

Comment: No-no, I want to switch to another view controller.

Answer (score 0):

We can select an appropriate view from the view tab and slide show tab.There are also buttons avaliable at the bottom right corner of the PowerPoint window.We can click any one of them to change the view.