# How to switch from one view to another in iPhone?

Tags: objective-c

I am a beginner in objective-c. Can anyone please tell me how can I switch from one view to another in an iPhone application.

Comment: You should be more specific about exactly what you are trying to do.  Are you using a navigation controller or a tab bar controller?  Have you looked at any of Apple's sample code?  Have you read any documentation?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845188/how-to-switch-from-one-view-to-another

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[View Programming Guide for iOS](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/Introduction/Introduction.html)

[iPhone View Switching Tuturial](http://fuelyourcoding.com/iphone-view-switching-tutorial/)

[How To Switch Views using Multiple Viewcontrollers (Method 1)](http://www.iphoneapptuts.com/iphone-3-0/how-to-switch-views-using-multiple-viewcontrollers-method-1/)

[Switching Views with Animation](http://www.iphoneapptuts.com/iphone-3-0/switching-views-bonus-animation/)

[How to animate View swap on simple View iPhone App?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/983598/how-to-animate-view-swap-on-simple-view-iphone-app)

[switch between uiviews with buttons and not uinavigation controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/959023/switch-between-uiviews-with-buttons-and-not-uinavigation-controllers)

[Switch between UIViewControllers using UISegmentedControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5555218/switch-between-uiviewcontrollers-using-uisegmentedcontrol)

Answer (score 4):

There are 3 main controllers that can switch views for you:

- UINavigationController

  - Here you push and pop views in a chain.
  - There will be a navigation bar on top which lets you navigate back to where you came from.
- UITabbarController

  - Here all the views will be represented by tabs at the bottom of the screen.
  - You can switch back and forward between them by clicking them in the tabbar.
- UIViewController

  - There is a method in UIViewController wich lets you "present" other viewcontrollers. It's called presentModalViewController:animated:
  - You will have to do your own navigation back to the parent by using dismissViewControllerAnimated:

You can also do your own switching with variations of addSubView: or view.hidden or similar, but I would recommend those 3 to begin with.